# Have an enjoyable visit to OR of the exhibition?

Tags: prepositions

I'm not sure which preposition is better suited here. Do I say: *I hope you have an enjoyable visit to the exhibition* or *I hope you have an enjoyable visit of the exhibition*

I would also greatly appreciate any tips about different ways or templates to formulate sentences that convey your wish that someone a nice flight/visit/trip/ experience in a formal way intended for an email.

Comment: What efforts did you make to find the answer? I Googled "visit to the exhibition" and "visit of the exhibition" and got very different results. (There are certainly better places to check than Google web search, but that's just an example.)

Comment: If it's known what you are talking about, it might be more natural to simply say "Enjoy your visit!".

Answer (score 1):

*To* is the correct preposition, but a more idiomatic phrasing would be:

> I hope you enjoy visiting the exhibition.

Or just:

> I hope you enjoy the exhibition.

Often imperatives are used with "enjoy" in such situations, so the following would also work:

> Enjoy the exhibition!